# How to create Parameter Key filter in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

[I send this event to Google Analytics with this data and in the reports tab I wanted to make some filters using these parameter keys, is there a way to do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUuhq.png)

I tried everything here and I still haven't succeeded. helpe me